# XML Cross Reference

Tags: python, ruby, xml, perl, scripting

I have an XML file that contains an ID and another XML file that contains the same ID.
I would like to cross reference these files and extract information from the second file. 
The first file contains only those ID's that I need.
For example the first file contains the ID's 345, 350, 353, 356
and the second file contains the ID's 345,346,347,348,349,350 ....
I want to extract the data node and all of its children from the second file.

The first file structure:

```
<data>
    <node>
        <info>info</info>
        <id>345</id>
    </node>
    <node2>
        <node3>
                <info2>info</info2>
                <id>2</id>
        </node3>
        <otherinfo>1</otherinfo>
        <text type = "02">
                <role>info</role>
                <st>1</st>
        </text>
    </node2>
</data>
```

The second file structure:

```
<data>
    <node>
        <info>info</info>
        <id>345</id>
    </node>
    <node2>And a bunch of other nodes</node2>
    <node2>And a bunch of other nodes</node2>
    <node2>And a bunch of other nodes</node2>
</data>
```

I have tried a ruby/nokogiri solution but I can't seem to get very far. 
I'm open to solutions in any scripting language.

Comment: You might be interested in [XPointer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xptr-framework/) and check that the XML library you're using supports it.

Otherwise you'll have to parse the second file and keep the id/node pairs in a data structure (dict in Python, hash in Perl). Then you parse the first and lookup for ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract all `id` values from the first xml string:

```
from lxml import etree

e1 = etree.fromstring(xml1)
ids = e1.xpath('//id/text()')
```

To extract all `<node>` elements from the second xml string that are parents to `id` elements with known `id` values from the first one:

```
import re

e2 = etree.fromstring(xml2)
ns_re = dict(re="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions")
re_id = "|".join(map(re.escape, ids))
nodes = e2.xpath("//id[re:test(.,'^(?:%s)$')]/parent::node" % re_id,
                 namespaces=ns_re)
```

Comment: This is awesome thank you so much. I did notice though that the regex is matching ids like 222 and 3222.

Comment: @tstrokes: You're right. I've added parentheses to avoid matching partial strings.